# Бесконечный цикл и Socket Linux

Tags: linux, c, unix-socket

Товарищи специалисты, требуется ваша помощь. Написал программу на СИ, которая выполняет в бесконечном цикле. Появилась необходимость межпроцессорного взаимодействия. Воспользовался файловым сокетом и тут понял, что цикл мой не работает. Это и понятно. Сокет ждёт соединения принимает его выполняет одну итерацию моей программы и опять ждёт. Начал искать инфу. Все концы идут к fork(). Вопрос: это то что мне нужно? 
Ещё раз. У меня есть программа которая должна выполняться без остановки, но когда через сокет передам данные она должна принять их, скорректировать значение и продолжить работу. 
Если что то не понятно, уточните в комментариях.

Comment: вопрос закалючается только в "Вопрос: это то что мне нужно?" ? тогда ответ: да, сойдет как один из способов решения.

Comment: Мне в fork() параметры передавать нужно будет, что бы моя программа корректировала свою работу. Или это через те же сокеты?

Comment: Вам нужен сискол select (в линукс ещё можно poll) в не блокирующем режиме.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо использования многопоточности, у вас еще есть вариант использовать асинхронный ввод-вывод. То есть, на каждой итерации вашего цикла вы должны будете проверять, нет ли для вас данных в сокете, и, если они есть, обрабатывать эту ситуацию.

[Статья на английском по теме](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html)

Рекомендую [книгу Снейдера](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/126048/) для изучения работы с сокетами.

Чтобы получше разобраться, как вообще пишутся околосистемные вещи, почитайте [Побегайло](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2575245/)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас изучу

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду fork() - это многопоточность, а асинхронный ввода вывода это - что то вроде сигналов?

Comment: Как на Ваш взгляд, что лучше будет работать. Скорость важна.

Comment: Асинхронный ввод-вывод можно реализовать не только через сигналы

Comment: понимаю. Я уточняю. Начинаю в этом только разбираться.

Comment: На мой взгляд, вы подталкиваете меня к решению проблемы XY (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Сформулируйте, какую задачу мы решаем более подробно и обобщенно.

Comment:  понял. Сейчас сделаю

Comment: 1. Программа которая должна работать в бесконечном цикле. 2. Мне нравится использовать сокет, так как его с лёгкостью можно будет переделать под сетевой вариант работы. 3. Мне нужно передавать аргументы в мой цикл, что бы программа корректировала значения вычислений.  4. Я сталкнулся с проблемой, которую описал выше. Мой цикл ждёт сообщения от сокета. 5. То решение которое нашел на просторах говорит мне использовать fork() "многопоточность", Вы мне подсказали что ещё можно использовать асинхронный ввод/вывод. Делаю вывод: нужно разобраться с чем то одним. Что лучше подойдет?

Comment: Или это вообще без разницы? Я так понимаю они оба будут дружить с сокетом.

Comment: Фокус в том, что в данном случае вы вообще можете обойтись стандарными потоками ввода - вывода, а для переделки под сетевой вариант использовать xinetd

Вы можете просто смотреть, не появились ли новые данные в стандартном вводе вашей программы (!feof(stdin)) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948723/checking-the-stdin-buffer-if-its-empty), и, если они появились, читать их и обрабатывать. А ответы писать в stdout

Comment: Вы - мастер. Спасибо. Буду думать.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы рекомендовали книгу. Можно полное ее название и автора. По обрывкам ничего не находит.

Comment: Дополнил ответ ссылкой

Comment: Принял. Спасибо

Comment: Принял. Спасибо

Comment: Здравствуйте. Хочу у Вас уточнить. Написал socket с использованием epoll. По обещаю сети, это не блокирующий io, теперь главный вопрос. Как проверить что он не блокирующийся ?? Просто кино какое то.

Comment: Если при создании сокета ошибок не было, он создался неблокирующим. Я вам очень советую прочитать всего Снейдера, а не только интересующий вас кусок.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Сделаю как Вы сказали

Comment: Я добавил еще одну полезную книгу в ответ